# Inserting values in column using select command

Tags: postgresql

I have used the following code-

```
alter table locality_town_overlap_v1 
add column Area_L_T double precision 

insert into locality_town_overlap_v1(Area_L_T) 
values (Select ST_Area(ST_Transform(locality_town_overlap_v1.geom,32645)) as area from locality_town_overlap_v1)
```

but getting error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Select"
LINE 4: values (Select ST_Area(ST_Transform(locality_town_overlap_v1...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to surround the subselect with an additional pair of parentheses.

But it would be better to just write

```
INSERT INTO locality_town_overlap_v1(Area_L_T) SELECT ...
```

Comment: I executed this codes  insert into locality_town_overlap_v1(Area_L_T) 
select ST_Area(ST_Transform(geom,32645))from locality_town_overlap_v1; but value was not inserted in the column

Comment: Was there an error message? Does the `SELECT` return any rows?

Comment: No, there was no any error query executed but column was still empty. Whereas select ST_Area(ST_Transform(geom,32645))from locality_town_overlap_v1 return the area.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Can you come up with a complete test case that makes the behavior reproducible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make insert (create new row) not just update information for existing records in column "Area_L_T"?

Comment: I have to add a new column in existing table to store the area of geometry so am using add column and insert, and I have also used  update command which is still running

Comment: That sounds like it should be an `UPDATE`. You'll need to provide a complete example so we can understand what is going on.